# Finding a specific item in a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

First of all, I know that a vector would be much easier for this. However, this is for a class and the list helps with sorting. Now, I have a list of pointers to Sprite objects. I would like to start with the second item in the list and run some methods on them but I'm not sure how to start with the 2nd item, and also how to access the Sprites functions from within the list.

Here is the code in question.

```
    list<Sprite*>::iterator iter = sprites.begin();
    iter++;
    iter++;
    while (iter != sprites.end())               //Missile Movement
    {
        dynamic_cast<Missile*>(sprites[iter])->Update();

        if (!dynamic_cast<Missile*>(sprites[iter])->GetActive())
        {
            delete sprites[iter];
            sprites.erase(iter--);
        }

        iter++;
    }
```

Currently the code is set up to use a vector of Sprite pointers. I cannot use the current code to call Update or GetActive on the objects. Can you guys help me understand how to change the syntax to change *sprites* to a list?

Comment: There are problems: (1) calling `++` when the list could have fewer than 2 elements; (2) not checking `dynamic_cast` for null (you shouldn't need `dynamic_cast` at all if the `Update` function is `virtual`).

Comment: How about `if (sprites.size() > 2)` before embarking on this ensuing madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list<Sprite*>::iterator iter = sprites.begin();
if (sprites.size() < 2) throw std::runtime_error("too few sprites");
iter++;
iter++;
while (iter != sprites.end())               //Missile Movement
{
    if (Missile* p = dynamic_cast<Missile*>(*iter))
    {
        p->Update();
        if (!p->GetActive())
        {
            delete p;
            iter = sprites.erase(iter);
        }
        else
            ++iter;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "WARN: sprite is not a missile\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this accesses the third sprite (OP did say "second sprite" in his text description , but then gave code for accessing the third sprite)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using index notation sprites[iter], just dereference the iterator, as *iter.

Also, the erase() call will give problems, as the object has been destroyed by the time it is post-decremented.  Instead use the return value such as iter = sprites.erase(iter); and the decrementing if you need to for your logic.